# How to predict on new data row using trained XGB classification model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I trained a model with and got a decent auc. Now, I want to predict on completely new data but I am not sure how to. Can someone help?

```
# fit model no training data
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# make predictions for test data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]

#evaluate predictions train vs test data
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

Now, I have a brand new data I want to score with this model. How would I do this? Something predict.proba()?

Comment: You can fit the new complete data that you have read using pandas or whatever. Just again, defining NEW train and NEW test dataset. Then using the trained model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fitting new data

```
NEW_DTA = pd.read_csv(data)
New_y_test = NEW_DTA.iloc[:,-1]
New_x_test = NEW_DTA.drop(colums='Target')
New_pred = model.predict(New_x_test)
```